# Partial Template Specialization in C++ 98?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, c++98, visual-c++-6

Does C++ 98 support partial template specification?

The following code compiles fine under C++ 11, but doesn't compile in Visual C++ 6.0.
So I am wondering if the syntax needs to be slightly different or if it's just not supported:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename A, typename B> class Foo
{
public:
    static void bar(A a, B b)
    {
        std::cout << "A";
    };
};

template <typename A> class Foo<A, std::string>
{
public:
    static void bar(A a, std::string b)
    {
        std::cout << "B";
    };
};

template <typename B> class Foo<std::string, B>
{
public:
    static void bar(std::string a, B b)
    {
        std::cout << "C";
    };
};

template <> class Foo<std::string, std::string>
{
public:
    static void bar(std::string a, std::string b)
    {
        std::cout << "D";
    };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo<int, int>::bar(12, 42);
    Foo<int, std::string>::bar(12, "");
    Foo<std::string, int>::bar("", 42);
    Foo<std::string, std::string>::bar("", "");

    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
Compiling...
Test.cpp
C:\test\test.cpp(20) : error C2989: 'Foo<A,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >' : template class has already been defined as a non-template class
C:\test\test.cpp(20) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C:\test\test.cpp(29) : error C2989: 'Foo<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,A>' : template class has already been defined as a non-template class
C:\test\test.cpp(29) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
Error executing cl.exe.
 
Test.obj - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: C++ 98 supports partial specialisation, but VC++6 does not really support C++98. It has more bugs than an anthill. Why would anyone use it today?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Unfortunately, there is lots of legacy software out there which has to be maintained and which does not necessarily work with newer versions without spending lots of effort (and money).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 does not support partial template specialisation. It is a [known bug](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/240/Q240866/).

For more known standard compliance issues of VC++6.0, see [here](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/243/Q243451/).

---

*Archive links, since these KB articles seem to be removed from Microsoft databases*